# How to get an element from Controller?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I need to run 'legacy code' from inside of Controller and need to get element

```
 function EmailformController($scope) {
     // here I need to get current dom/jqueried element, how to do it? 
 }
```

Comment: Isn't it the element you're passing in as `$scope`?

Comment: Why not a directive? You probably CAN do this in a directive but is too much focused on controller.

Comment: If you think about: console.log($($scope).html()); it will return null

Comment: Directive may help this out. Thanks for hint :)

Comment: You can also inject `$element` into your controller, but you usually want to use a directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use a directive. You should never be dealing with DOM elements inside of a controller. Only your business logic should go into the controller, DOM manipulation should go in a directive.